# How i can increase the Block settings limit?

Tags: features

We are implementing blocks through [features](https://www.drupal.org/project/features) and [features extra](https://www.drupal.org/project/features_extra) module.

Here only 50 blocks are displaying in `admin>structure>features>create Components`. We want to increase that limit to **100**. Please find the attached snapshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things you could do for increasing the limit on blocks that you can add to your site. For instance, have you tried increasing max_input_vars limit in your .htaccess or in your php.ini file? From 1000 to, let's say, 2000?

Or increasing your limit in your settings.php file if not?

See if this post here (its second half rather) can be of any help: https://www.optasy.com/blog/how-add-more-lot-more-blocks-your-drupal-site

Comment: Thank you @OPTASY, After increasing the limit max_input_vars to 2200. same problem.